VScode : 'remote-ssh: connect to host' resulted in an error. cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'after'). Not-willingly in Admin mode
I am usually working on VScode, adapting scripts that are on a remote server through the VScode extension SSH-remote. Recently the cluster I'm using crashed, since then I cannot connect to ssh host on vs-code anymore. I am however able to connect to the cluster through vscode terminal or any other terminal.
The command Remote-ssh: connect to host shows the error: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'after').
I tried the following without success:

deleting things (cache, .vscode-server, .ssh/config)
enable "Remote Server Listen On Socket" (cannot run command "Kill VS Code Server on Host" afterward as required, displays same error "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'after').
Going to the pre-release version of SSH-remote

I know another user of VScode and the same cluster has not this issue. That's why I believe the problem is on my side, in particular my VScode always run as administrator giving me the warning : "Updates are disabled because you are running the user-scope installation of Visual Studio Code as Administrator.". However, I tried to download it again and couldn't make it run as a non-admin user. From reading around I understood that this is due to my version of windows that doesn't allow to create another user. There is only one user which is also the Administrator.
Anyone encountered the same issue or have suggestions?
Thanks!

UPDATE : I succeeded running VScode as a basic user without admin rights but get the same error...
